# error starting todos example

Tags: meteor

noob here. on linux, i installed meteor, tried to load 'todos' app, got this error. it seems to be related to file system monitoring?  am i missing a package or perm?  i installed meteor with sudo, but i installed the 'todos' as my basic user.

thanks in advance!

```
~$ mkdir meteorDev
~$ cd meteorDev/
~/meteorDev$ meteor create --example todos
todos: created.

To run your new app:
   cd todos
   meteor
~/meteorDev$ cd todos/
~/meteorDev/todos$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/meteorDev/todos ]]]]]

Running on: http://localhost:3000/

fs.js:663
    throw errnoException(errno, 'watch');
          ^
Error: watch EMFILE
    at errnoException (fs.js:636:11)
    at FSWatcher.start (fs.js:663:11)
    at Object.watch (fs.js:691:11)
    at [object Object]._scan (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:322:12)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/meteor/app/lib/third/underscore.js:76:11)
    at new <anonymous> (/usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:264:5)
    at /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:455:17
    at /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:512:5
    at /usr/lib/meteor/app/meteor/run.js:570:9
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I am using Debian 6 and tried to run as root, tried to increase the inotify instances (inotify works fine with guard btw). I even tried to install mongodb seperatly. Seems to be that is not necessary, because meteor runs it's own Mongo.

Comment: I tried again under Linux Mint Debian (wheezy/sid), and now works great. Only on our server, I got that problem :(

Comment: Not sure why, but if I run just `meteor` I get this error message. If I run it as `sudo meteor` I do not

Answer (score 11):

Meteor uses node's "fs.watch" command, which uses linux's inotify API. It is possible your system does not have inotify support, or it is turned off. Try this to see if you have inotify enabled:

```
 cat /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

If that file exists and has a low number in it, try this **as root** to up the limit:

```
 echo 8192 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances
```

If that file does not exist, it is likely your system does not support inotify or it is somehow turned off.

The increase in max_user_instances is temporary and won't persist after a reboot. To make it permanent:

```
 echo fs.inotify.max_user_instances=8192 | sudo tee /etc/sysctl.d/10-inotify.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Comment: I needed this on a virtual machine I'm running can we have a common issues section on the meteor.com site perhaps?

Comment: FAQ section needed as a priority, this just happened to me on Ubuntu, randomly our of the blue and crashed Meteor.

Comment: I got a similar error that cannot be fixed by tweaking max_user_instances but max_user_watches instead. So I had to do this in My Fedora 16 (64 bit) machine:

# echo 10000 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches
# echo 10000 > /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_instances

Answer (score 0):

Do you have MongoDB installed? Try running it in another shell.

```
mongod
```

Comment: i did not install it, but checking processes, i have mongod running from under my meteor installation:

`/usr/lib/meteor/mongodb/bin/mongod --bind_ip 127.0.0.1 --port 3002 --dbpath /home/bmurrell/meteorDev/todos/.meteor/local/db`